# Add multiple times $selected$ in a VS 2015 snippet

Tags: xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, doxygen, code-snippets

I'm writing a code snippet for doxygen comments for C/C++ on Visual Studio 2015 (using XML).

I can't achieve to write something like :

```
 /**
 * \fn $selected$
 * \brief $BRIEF$
 * 
 * \param $TYPE_PARAM$ $NAME_VAR$ $BRIEF_PARAM$
 * \return $TYPE_RETURN$ $VALUES$
 * */
$selected$;
$end$
```

I want $selected$ to be written after `\fn` and just before `;`. But this syntax returns me this :

```
 /**
  * \fn
  * \brief BRIEF
  *
  * \param TYPE_PARAM NAME_VAR BRIEF_PARAM
  * \return TYPE_RETURN VALUES
  * */
void foo(int param);
```

with nothing is written after `\fn`.

Can you guys help me understand?

Comment: For doxygen the `\fn` is not necessary in case the comment block is directly in front of the function (definition).

Comment: @albert ok thanks! And would it be possible to decompose $selected$ to get the return type, parameter type and variable name?

Comment: This would probably be something for VS, I don't use VS.

Comment: @albert the snippet file are written in xml

Comment: No idea how that works, VS issue I think. I just saw on the last line of the comment : `* */` probably better  / nicer to just use `*/`

Comment: Well, it doesn't look like you can do any of that with snippets, but I just want to point out that Doxygen doesn't actually want types passed to [\param](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparam) or [\return](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdreturn): this notation is meant for staticly-typed code, where Doxygen can (hopefully) get this information by parsing the code. (C++ is notoriously difficult to parse correctly, though. Anything that can do so is like 90% of a C++ compiler already.)